# Can not link the author

Tags: wordpress

I am Making a blog site. I want to show all posts of a user by linking with his/her user name. But it's not working. My code is

```
 by <a href="<?php get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID'));?>"><?php the_author();?></a>
```

What's wrong with it actually?

Comment: you are missing echo

Comment: Make sure that the_author() is used in loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a>
```